# Moving nodes based on a matching value

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have the following input xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
   <PQContact>
      <input>
         <folder>
            <UNITCD>CS2XAA</UNITCD>
            <FOLDERID>KKMTEST3000</FOLDERID>
         </folder>
      </input>
      <input>
         <folder>
            <UNITCD>CS2XAA</UNITCD>
            <FOLDERID>KKMTEST1300</FOLDERID>
         </folder>
      </input>
   </PQContact>
   <AWD>
      <case>
         <RMEM>KKMTEST3000</RMEM>
         <transaction>ABC</transaction>
      </case>
      <case>
         <RMEM>KKMTEST1300</RMEM>
         <transaction>DEF</transaction>
      </case>
   </AWD>
</ROOT>
```

I have to move the cases under `/ROOT/AWD` to `<folder>` of `/ROOT/PQContact/input` if the value of `<RMEM>` tag under `<case>` matches with the value of `<FOLDERID>` tag under `<folder>`.

My resultant xml should be as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
   <PQContact>
      <input>
         <folder>
            <UNITCD>CS2XAA</UNITCD>
            <FOLDERID>KKMTEST3000</FOLDERID>
            <case>
               <RMEM>KKMTEST3000</RMEM>
               <transaction>ABC</transaction>
            </case>
         </folder>
      </input>
      <input>
         <folder>
            <UNITCD>CS2XAA</UNITCD>
            <FOLDERID>KKMTEST1300</FOLDERID>
            <case>
               <RMEM>KKMTEST1300</RMEM>
               <transaction>DEF</transaction>
            </case>
         </folder>
      </input>
   </PQContact>
   <AWD />
</ROOT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using an `xsl:key` to look up the `case` elements:

```
<xsl:key name="case" match="case" use="RMEM" />
```

Then, you can have a template that matches the `folder` element that copies the existing node, but also copies the matching `case` element using the key.

```
<xsl:template match="folder">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('case', FOLDERID)" />
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Combine this with the [XSLT identity template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform), then the only thing that is needed is a template to ensure `AWD` is not copied too.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:key name="case" match="case" use="RMEM" />

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="folder">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="key('case', FOLDERID)" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="AWD" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```